# My app is incompatible for android 2.3.6 (samsung galaxy y) on google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-2.3-gingerbread, incompatibility

My app is incompatible with Samsung galaxy y (android 2.3.6) on Google play. I am able to search and install my app on all other version of android, but on devices running android 2.3.6, my app is not searchable and if searched using direct URL shows incompatibility message.

This is my manifest....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.hadithdoPro" android:versionName="1.0.1" 
android:installLocation="internalOnly" 
android:versionCode="6">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="Hadith.do Pro">
        <activity android:name="hadithdo.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="hadithdo.BookReader">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="hadithdo.Activity1" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="hadithdo.Activity1" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <receiver android:name="hadithdo.OnBootNotificationAlertReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>`
```

Comment: Did you find it out?

Comment: no it is still incompatible